# Strange view error on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have some cotroller like this:

```
Route::get('/article/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
```

and here's my ArticlesController@create:

```
public function create(){
        return view('articles.create',
            [
                'title'=>'Add Artikel',
                'username'=>'Whatever Myname',
                'status' => 'Offline'
            ]
        );
    }
```

when i trying to access blog.dev/article/create i got this strange errors:

```
"Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\articles\single.blade.php)"
```

how come i can get this kind of error when my view is pointing at articles.create but the error is at single.blade.php which it suppose for ArticlesController@view?

this is what in create.blade.php:

```
@extends('admin.layout')
@section('content')
    <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Horizontal Form</h3>
        </div>
        @include('admin.formerrors')
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="/articles">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Judul Artikel">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Content</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="content" name="content"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

and here's in my single.blade.php :

```
@extends('admin.layout')
@section('content')
    <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $article->content }}</p>
    <hr>
    @foreach($article->comments as $comment)
        <blockquote>
            <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
            <small>{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</small>
        </blockquote>
    @endforeach
    @include('admin.formerrors')
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="/article/{{ $article->id }}/comment">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comment</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

and here's my router:

```
Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index')->name('home'); 
Route::post('/articles', 'ArticlesController@save'); 
Route::get('/article/{id}', 'ArticlesController@view'); 
Route::get('/article/create', 'ArticlesController@create'); 

Route::post('/article/{article}/comment', 'CommentsController@save'); 

Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create'); 
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');
```

I try to change the create function by pointing into another view, but still it showing same error and pointing at single.blade view.

I delete all code at single.blade and write 'test' text, i don't get any errors. but i'm pointing my controller for viewing into create.blade not sigle.blade

Comment: share the blade

Comment: May be `single.blade.php` is included in the `articles.create` as a partial !!

Comment: Ok please wait i will post the blade of it.

Comment: Please share code for display single.blade.php

Comment: @Maraboc no they not included as partial. i already add the blade file in the question.

Comment: may be also caused by a redirect for example if a user can not create a post i will be redirected to a url with the single view !!

Comment: @Maraboc no, i just access it directly without using post.

Comment: Is the problem solved ??

Comment: @Maraboc i edit the question with something that i already try. I got no error but why it's pointing into incorrect view?

Comment: And in the browser you get `test` ?

Comment: since it's pointing into single.blade it give an errors since no data given.

Comment: yes it showing 'test' text without any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156670/discussion-between-maraboc-and-henra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing you routes the problem is in this two routes :

```
Route::get('/article/{id}', 'ArticlesController@view');
Route::get('/article/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
```

In this case Laravel will consider the create in your path `blog.dev/article/create` as an `id` parameter of the view route here => `/article/{id}`.

So as a solution you should simply inverse the two routes :

```
Route::get('/article/create', 'ArticlesController@create');
Route::get('/article/{id}', 'ArticlesController@view');
```

Comment: Work greats. Thanks. :D

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find what's in the file by reading more than just that line. Maybe you're including that file in the articles.create? Maybe you're accessing a variable that doesn't exist whenever you load the page. Edit your answer with more of the error and what's inside both blades and we can pinpoint what's wrong.